# Can anybody confirm that ExpressJS is slower than Spring Boot?

Tags: java, performance, spring-boot, express

we are currently investigating whether ExpressJS (Nodejs) or SpringBoot (Java) is better suited for backend operation. We wrote some "equivalent" code with Rest interfaces, some accessing databases (eg MongoDB) and making some transforms. Both applications run on the same server instance.

When it comes to load testing, we observe that avg response time is longer for ExpressJS even in small-load operation and becomes even worse when scaling up to 40 parallel requests....

Can you guys confirm that observation - do we have to say in general that expressjs/nodejs web application backends are not as fast as using springboot/java? Or is that a result of missing multithreading in expressjs?

Thanks!

Comment: Does https://dzone.com/articles/web-development-comparison-springboot-vs-expressjs help you?

Comment: Or https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r9 or https://github.com/networknt/microservices-framework-benchmark/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Oh, and node.js does have threads, both internally and for you to program with - [WorkerThreads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html).  Also, you would code for scale differently in node.js than other environments so one can't really evaluate two environments if you're using the exact same approach for scaling with both.  You have to know each environment and code to its strength to successfully evaluate what it is capable of.  Also watch out for the memory usage and CPU effectiveness with purely threaded solutions as the number of requests in flight at the same time increases.

Answer (score 0):

I use autocannon (npm) to loadtest and the result:

**Express.js**

Running 10s test @ http://localhost:3000/
10 connections

| Stat | 2.5% | 50% | 97.5% | 99% | Avg | Stdev | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Latency | 0 ms | 1 ms | 4 ms | 7 ms | 1.16 ms | 1.25 ms | 20 ms |

| Stat | 1% | 2.5% | 50% | 97.5% | Avg | Stdev | Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Req/Sec | 5011 | 5011 | 6351 | 6671 | 6024.91 | 640.58 | 5010 |
| Bytes/Sec | 1.2 MB | 1.2 MB | 1.52 MB | 1.6 MB | 1.45 MB | 154 kB | 1.2 MB |

Req/Bytes counts sampled once per second.
# of samples: 11
66k requests in 11.03s, 15.9 MB read

---

**Springboot**

Running 10s test @ http://localhost:8080/employee
10 connections

| Stat | 2.5% | 50% | 97.5% | 99% | Avg | Stdev | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Latency | 2 ms | 42 ms | 131 ms | 142 ms | 51.6 ms | 38.29 ms | 207 ms |

| Stat | 1% | 2.5% | 50% | 97.5% | Avg | Stdev | Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Req/Sec | 10455 | 10455 | 12959 | 17199 | 14020 | 2638.61 | 10454 |
| Bytes/Sec | 1.26 MB | 1.26 MB | 1.56 MB | 2.07 MB | 1.69 MB | 319 kB | 1.26 MB |

Req/Bytes counts sampled once per second.
# of samples: 10
142k requests in 10.04s, 16.9 MB read

Comment: State the values in a list fashion, since tables aren't supported here.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the similar thing I have observed express is much slower as compared to Spring Boot, Spring boot gives the best performance because it is powered by Java, (JVM - architecture) which uses Just In Time compiler to boost the performance...

You can definitely go for Spring Boot, which is the beast !!